# Samsung 7 Graphics Nightmare

Tags: 12.04, ati, samsung, hybrid-graphics

I just bought a Samsung 7 laptop with the Amd Radeon hd 6490m an I installed the driver. Everything was working smooth and it was rendering nice until I rebooted it. I noticed that it wouldn't boot my favorite game because of a GLSBadRenderRequest. So I went over to the AMD Catalyst program, and it wouldn't fire up because it couldn't find the graphics card!! What do you think is going on? Oh, and that was the latest driver straight from AMD. Im running 12.04lts.

Comment: Uninstall the driver and try again? if it was the latest from AMD it should bring support for your card, and watch for any errors.

Comment: 12.04 is EOL. VTC this unanswered question as `not reproducible`.